# How to access Gerrit Rest API using python

Tags: python, gerrit

Firstly, I've a limited gerrit understanding.

I'm trying to access Gerrit Rest API using python, but not able to do so. I want to fetch all the information related to accounts (commits, reviews).

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI, HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx.com/', auth = auth)
changes = rest.get("changes/?q=is:open&q=is:close&q=all&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&o=ALL_REVISIONS&o=ALL_COMMITS&o=ALL_FILES&o=MESSAGES", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xx.xxx.xxx.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /login/a/changes/?q=is:open&q=is:close&q=all&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&o=ALL_REVISIONS&o=ALL_COMMITS&o=ALL_FILES&o=MESSAGES (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x825bad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

I'm able to fetch the information if I copy paste the query in the url, but not thru python. How to do it?
Please comment / edit if question is not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are encountering a Connection Error from the requests library(pygerrit2 is [dependent on requests](https://github.com/dpursehouse/pygerrit2/blob/master/requirements.txt)) - it is occurring because your connection is timing out. To avoid this I recommend using a library like [backoff](https://github.com/litl/backoff). Backoff will catch this connection Error and retry establishing the connection. This is done easily with a decorator and an import.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI, HTTPBasicAuth
import backoff
import requests

@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, 
                      requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
                      max_time=10)
def makeGerritAPICall():
     auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password')
     rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx.com/', auth = auth)
     changes = rest.get("changes/?q=is:open&q=is:close&q=all&o=DETAILED_ACCOUNTS&o=ALL_REVISIONS&o=ALL_COMMITS&o=ALL_FILES&o=MESSAGES", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

The following function will retry making any request that encounters a ConnectionError for 10 seconds before failing and raising a ConnectionError.

I would recommend visiting the backoff git README docs as they contain tons of useful info about backoff.

Comment: am a complete beginner here. How do I print the values which I get in changes variable?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of @spencer.pinegar.
You should add the following code above the function that is performing the request:

```py
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo,
                      requests.exceptions.RequestException,
                      max_tries=8, max_time=60)
```